# Laravel 5.1 Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am upgrading my current application to a laravel framework, I have an existing database of users and passwords.

I have connected the user model to the right table, and I've also updated the password of one of the users to bcrypt so I can test the log in.

The log in works fine and redirects to the dashboard as you'd expect, however, whenever I try to return the Auth::user() I get nothing?

Here's my auth model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'existing_users_table';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

Comment: please check first you are logged in or not by this code 
if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
}

Comment: Where are you calling Auth::user(), can you post the code?

Comment: or use $userId = Auth::id();

Comment: sorry guys, after further investigation it appears the site isn't logging me in. it is still looking at the users table even though I've specified the protected table.. @PardeepPathania

Comment: When trying to create a new user by posting to auth/register I get the following: SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'users'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [users] where [email] = test@test.com) - I'm not sure why the users table is still being called.

Comment: Check config/auth.php. `'table' => 'users',`